# `How to use CAS for web service authentication?

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-security, cas

I am currently using`struts`, `spring` and `hibernate` in my application. I'm using `CAS` for authentication. The table containing the user name and password fields are mentioned in the `deploymentConfigContext.xml` of the CAS war file.

Using spring security how can I implement the same in my application for web services?

How is the username and password given from a client invoking my web services?

Answer (score 0):

Your WS is protected by some sort of CAS filter, that is perhaps provided by Spring Security. When a request comes in, the filter intercepts and redirects to CAS login. User logs in, and they go back to the WS. Filter intercepts the request again, validates the ticket and moves onto the WS